# f# interactive won't tab complete in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#-interactive

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here (I'm new to both F# and VS) but I can't get the tab completion to work in F# Interactive.

- I have `--readline` enabled in `Tools
  -> Options -> F# Tools -> F# Interactive`
- `fsi.exe --readline`
  from cmd does work

I'm on Win7 professional and I'm running a trial version of Visual Studio 2010 Professional. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

VS F# Interactive Shell is just a normal text editor which enables us to write input to fsi.exe and display the output of it. Being a text editor, it will handles tab key like others do. You are not doing wrong. The feature is not just there.

Comment: Ah ha, in that case is there anyway I can bind a key combination to do that? (Maybe Ctrl-Enter like the main window)

Comment: As far as I know there are no ways to achieve it currently.